# An unknown error occurred when fetching the script in a Chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vite

I'm trying to build a small Tamagotchi-like extension to learn how to develop extensions, I've used ChatGPT for some of it, and I have an issue, after building the extension and uploading the dist folder to chrome I get this issue

```
Service worker registration failed. Status code: 3
--------------------------------------------------

{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Virtual Pet Game",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Take care of your virtual pet directly from your browser.",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/virtual_pet_icon_16x16.png",
        "48": "images/virtual_pet_icon_48x48.png",
        "128": "images/virtual_pet_icon_128x128.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/virtual_pet_icon_16x16.png",
      "48": "images/virtual_pet_icon_48x48.png",
      "128": "images/virtual_pet_icon_128x128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "alarms"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js",
      "type": "module"
    }
  }
```

And

```
An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
Context: Unknown
Stack: :0 (anonim function)
```

This is my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Virtual Pet",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Take care of your virtual pet directly from your browser.",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/virtual_pet_icon_16x16.png",
        "48": "images/virtual_pet_icon_48x48.png",
        "128": "images/virtual_pet_icon_128x128.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/virtual_pet_icon_16x16.png",
      "48": "images/virtual_pet_icon_48x48.png",
      "128": "images/virtual_pet_icon_128x128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "alarms"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js",
      "type": "module"
    }
  }
```

And this is the worker file

```
import { IPetState, Pet } from "./gameLogic/Pets";

// Initialize a Pet instance outside of any functions to persist state
const pet = new Pet();

// Function to load pet state from storage and update the pet instance
function loadPetState(): void {
  chrome.storage.local.get(["petState"], (result) => {
    if (result.petState) {
      try {
        const loadedState: IPetState = JSON.parse(result.petState);
        pet.setPetState(loadedState);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error parsing pet state", error);
      }
    }
  });
}

// Function to save pet state to storage
function savePetState(): void {
  const petState = JSON.stringify(pet.getPetState());
  chrome.storage.local.set({ petState }, () => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error("Error saving state:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
      console.log("Pet state saved.");
    }
  });
}

// Load pet state when the extension starts or is installed
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(loadPetState);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(loadPetState);

// Message listener for actions from the content script or popup
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log("Message received:", message);
  console.log("Sender:", sender);
  if (message.command === "getPetState") {
    sendResponse({ petState: pet.getPetState() });
  } else if (message.command === "updatePetState" && message.payload.action) {
    const action = message.payload.action;
    if (typeof pet[action as keyof Pet] === "function") {
      (pet[action as keyof Pet] as () => void)(); // Ensure that pet[action] is callable by casting it to a function type
      savePetState();
      sendResponse({ success: true, petState: pet.getPetState() });
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid action called on Pet instance:", action);
    }
  }
  return true; // Keep the message channel open for asynchronous response
});

// Using Alarms API for periodic actions
if (chrome.alarms) {
  chrome.alarms.create("savePetState", { periodInMinutes: 1 });
  chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
    if (alarm.name === "savePetState") {
      savePetState();
    }
  });
} else {
  console.error("chrome.alarms is not available");
}
```

Finally this is the class I'm trying to import from

```
import evolutionPaths, { EvolutionRequirement } from "./Evolutions";

// In your Pet.ts or a separate types.ts file
export interface IPetState {
  hunger: number;
  happiness: number;
  health: number;
  discipline: number;
  sleep: number;
  bladder: number;
  weight: number;
  isSleeping: boolean;
  isSick: boolean;
  needsBathroom: boolean;
  isHungry: boolean;
  isUnhappy: boolean;
  isSleepy: boolean;
  hasLowHealth: boolean;
  currentStage: TStage;
  age: number;
  isAlive: boolean;
  neglectCounter: number;
  spriteFolder: string;
  // Add any other properties here
}

// Define the rates at which events hapen, should be in seconds
export interface IRates {
  [key: string]: number;
}
const RATES: IRates = {
  // once every 2 hours
  hunger: 1,
  hapiness: 2 * 60 * 60,
  neglect: 2 * 60 * 60,
  // once every 4 hours
  discipline: 4 * 60 * 60,
  // once a day
  age: 24 * 60 * 60,
};

export type TStage = "egg" | "baby" | "child" | "teen" | "adult";

export const NEGLECT_THRESHOLD = {
  happiness: 2,
  health: 2,
  hunger: 2,
  sleep: 2,
  bladder: 2,
};

const STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD = {
  happiness: 2,
  health: 4,
  hunger: 2,
  sleep: 4,
  bladder: 4,
};

export class Pet {
  hunger: number = 10;
  happiness: number = 10;
  health: number = 10;
  discipline: number = 10;
  sleep: number = 10;
  bladder: number = 10;
  weight: number = 1;
  isSleeping: boolean = false;
  isSick: boolean = false;
  needsBathroom: boolean = false;
  isHungry: boolean = false;
  isUnhappy: boolean = false;
  isSleepy: boolean = false;
  hasLowHealth: boolean = false;
  currentStage: TStage = "egg";
  age: number = 0;
  isAlive: boolean = true;
  neglectCounter: number = 0;
  spriteFolder: string = "defaultSpriteFolder"; // Ensure you have a default or make it optional

  elapsedTimeDict: { [key: string]: number } = {
    hunger: 0,
    happiness: 0,
    discipline: 0,
    sleep: 0,
    age: 0,
    neglect: 0,
    bladder: 0,
  };

  constructor(state?: Partial<IPetState>) {
    // Apply overrides from `state`
    if (state) {
      Object.assign(this, state);
    }
  }

  getPetState(): IPetState {
    return {
      hunger: this.hunger,
      happiness: this.happiness,
      health: this.health,
      discipline: this.discipline,
      sleep: this.sleep,
      bladder: this.bladder,
      weight: this.weight,
      isSleeping: this.isSleeping,
      isSick: this.isSick,
      needsBathroom: this.needsBathroom,
      isHungry: this.isHungry,
      isUnhappy: this.isUnhappy,
      isSleepy: this.isSleepy,
      hasLowHealth: this.hasLowHealth,
      currentStage: this.currentStage,
      age: this.age,
      isAlive: this.isAlive,
      neglectCounter: this.neglectCounter,
      spriteFolder: this.spriteFolder,
    };
  }

  setPetState(state: IPetState) {
    Object.assign(this, state);
  }

  gameTick(deltaTime: number) {
    // Implement logic for each tick, such as decrementing hunger, checking for evolution, etc.
    this.evolveIfNeeded();
    this.updateBasedOnTime(deltaTime);
  }

  updateBasedOnTime(deltaTime: number) {
    // Update each stat based on the elapsed time
    Object.keys(this.elapsedTimeDict).forEach((key) => {
      this.elapsedTimeDict[key] += deltaTime;
      if (this.elapsedTimeDict[key] >= RATES[key]) {
        this.updateStat(key);
        this.elapsedTimeDict[key] = 0; // Reset the timer for this attribute
      }
    });
  }

  updateStat(stat: string) {
    switch (stat) {
      case "hunger":
        this.hunger = Math.max(this.hunger - 1, 0);
        if (this.hunger < STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.hunger) {
          this.isHungry = true;
        }
        break;
      case "happiness":
        this.happiness = Math.max(this.happiness - 1, 0);
        if (this.happiness < STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.happiness) {
          this.isUnhappy = true;
        }
        break;
      case "age":
        this.age++;
        break;
      case "sleep":
        this.sleep = Math.max(this.sleep - 1, 0);
        if (this.sleep < STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.sleep) {
          this.isSleepy = true;
        }
        break;
      case "neglect":
        if (
          this.isHungry ||
          this.isUnhappy ||
          this.isSleepy ||
          this.hasLowHealth
        ) {
          this.neglectCounter++;
          this.health = Math.max(this.health - 1, 0);
        }
        break;
      case "discipline":
        this.discipline = Math.max(this.discipline - 1, 0);
        break;
      case "bladder":
        this.bladder = Math.max(this.bladder - 1, 0);
        if (this.bladder < STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.bladder) {
          this.needsBathroom = true;
        }
        break;
      // Handle other stats as necessary
    }
  }

  _feed(): void {
    this.hunger = Math.min(this.hunger + 1, 10);
    if (this.hunger >= STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.hunger) {
      this.isHungry = false;
    }
  }

  _play(): void {
    this.happiness = Math.min(this.happiness + 1, 10);
    if (this.happiness >= STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.happiness) {
      this.isUnhappy = false;
    }
  }

  _sleep(): void {
    this.sleep = Math.min(this.sleep + 1, 10);
    if (this.sleep >= STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.sleep) {
      this.isSleepy = false;
    }
  }

  _discipline(): void {
    this.discipline = Math.min(this.discipline + 1, 10);
  }

  _bathroom(): void {
    this.bladder = Math.min(this.bladder + 1, 10);
    if (this.bladder >= STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.bladder) {
      this.needsBathroom = false;
    }
  }

  _clean(): void {
    this.bladder = 0;
  }

  _cure(): void {
    this.isSick = false;
  }

  _wakeUp(): void {
    this.isSleeping = false;
  }

  _pet(): void {
    this.happiness = Math.min(this.happiness + 1, 10);
    if (this.happiness >= STATS_BAD_THRESHOLD.happiness) {
      this.isUnhappy = false;
    }
  }

  evolveIfNeeded() {
    const possibleEvolutions = evolutionPaths[this.currentStage];
    if (!possibleEvolutions) return; // No evolution path for this stage

    for (const evolutionOption of possibleEvolutions) {
      if (this.meetsRequirements(evolutionOption.requirements)) {
        this.currentStage = evolutionOption.nextEvolution as TStage;
        // Update sprite and other properties as necessary
        this.spriteFolder = evolutionOption.nextEvolution;
        // Handle other updates related to evolution
        break; // Stop checking once an evolution has occurred
      }
    }
  }

  meetsRequirements(requirements: EvolutionRequirement): boolean {
    // Check if the pet meets the requirements for the given evolution
    if (requirements.minimumAge && this.age < requirements.minimumAge) {
      return false;
    }
    if (requirements.minimumStats) {
      const { minimumStats } = requirements;
      if (minimumStats.happiness && this.happiness < minimumStats.happiness) {
        return false;
      }
      if (minimumStats.health && this.health < minimumStats.health) {
        return false;
      }
      if (minimumStats.hunger && this.hunger < minimumStats.hunger) {
        return false;
      }
      if (minimumStats.sleep && this.sleep < minimumStats.sleep) {
        return false;
      }
      if (
        minimumStats.discipline &&
        this.discipline < minimumStats.discipline
      ) {
        return false;
      }
      if (minimumStats.neglect && this.neglectCounter < minimumStats.neglect) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (requirements.specialConditions && !requirements.specialConditions()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  savePetState() {
    // Serialize the pet's current state to a JSON string
    const petState = JSON.stringify(this);
    console.log("Saving pet state:", petState);
    // Save it using the Chrome storage API
    chrome.storage.local.set({ petState }, () => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(`Error saving state: ${chrome.runtime.lastError}`);
      } else {
        console.log("Pet state saved successfully.");
      }
    });
  }

  loadPetState(callback: (pet: Pet) => void) {
    // Load the pet's state from the Chrome storage API
    chrome.storage.local.get(["petState"], (result) => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(`Error loading state: ${chrome.runtime.lastError}`);
      } else {
        const petState = result.petState;
        if (petState) {
          // Deserialize the pet's state from the JSON string and apply it
          const loadedPet = JSON.parse(petState);
          Object.assign(this, loadedPet);
        }
        callback(this); // Call the callback with the loaded state
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If I remove all the code from the worker file the worker loads just fine, I tried using a console.log there to check that it runs and it works, so the issue lies withing my worker file but honestly I'm new to extension developement and have no idea what the problem might be.

Thanks!!

EDIT: As a coment smartly pointed I missed adding an important file here that is being imported in the Pets class

Evolutions.ts file

```
export interface EvolutionRequirement {
  minimumAge?: number;
  minimumStats?: {
    hunger?: number;
    happiness?: number;
    health?: number;
    discipline?: number;
    sleep?: number;
    neglect?: number;
  };
  specialConditions?: () => boolean; // Function that returns true if special conditions are met
}

interface EvolutionOption {
  nextEvolution: string;
  requirements: EvolutionRequirement;
}

interface EvolutionPath {
  [speciesName: string]: EvolutionOption[];
}

const evolutionPaths: EvolutionPath = {
  egg: [
    {
      nextEvolution: "babyType1",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 1,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 7,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      nextEvolution: "babyType2",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 1,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 3,
          discipline: 5,
        },
      },
    },
    // Other possible evolutions from egg...
  ],
  baby: [
    {
      nextEvolution: "childType1",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 3,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 7,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      nextEvolution: "childType2",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 3,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 3,
          discipline: 5,
        },
      },
    },
    // Other possible evolutions from baby...
  ],
  teen: [
    {
      nextEvolution: "adultType1",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 5,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 7,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      nextEvolution: "adultType2",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 5,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 3,
          discipline: 5,
        },
      },
    },
    // Other possible evolutions from teen...
  ],
  adult: [
    {
      nextEvolution: "seniorType1",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 1,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 7,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      nextEvolution: "seniorType2",
      requirements: {
        minimumAge: 1,
        minimumStats: {
          happiness: 3,
          discipline: 5,
        },
      },
    },
    // Other possible evolutions from adult...
  ],
};

export default evolutionPaths;
```

EDIT 2: Just in case I'm also adding package.json file and a picture of how the dist folder looks after building

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-virtual-pet",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build && tsc && shx cp manifest.json dist/ && shx cp -R public/images dist/",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.259",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.14.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "shx": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}
```

Dist folder
[image: dist folder]

EDIT 3: I think I found the issue, the background.js file in the dist folder after building looks like this

```
import { Pet } from "./gameLogic/Pets";
// Initialize a Pet instance outside of any functions to persist state
const pet = new Pet();
// Function to load pet state from storage and update the pet instance
function loadPetState() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(["petState"], (result) => {
        if (result.petState) {
            try {
                const loadedState = JSON.parse(result.petState);
                console.log("Loaded pet state:", loadedState);
                pet.setPetState(loadedState);
                console.log("Pet state loaded. State is now:", pet.getPetState());
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error("Error parsing pet state", error);
            }
        }
    });
}
// Function to save pet state to storage
function savePetState() {
    const petState = JSON.stringify(pet.getPetState());
    chrome.storage.local.set({ petState }, () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error("Error saving state:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Pet state saved.");
        }
    });
}
// Load pet state when the extension starts or is installed
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(loadPetState);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(loadPetState);
// Message listener for actions from the content script or popup
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Message received:", message);
    console.log("Sender:", sender);
    if (message.command === "getPetState") {
        sendResponse({ petState: pet.getPetState() });
    }
    else if (message.command === "updatePetState" && message.payload.action) {
        const action = message.payload.action;
        if (typeof pet[action] === "function") {
            pet[action](); // Ensure that pet[action] is callable by casting it to a function type
            savePetState();
            sendResponse({ success: true, petState: pet.getPetState() });
        }
        else {
            console.error("Invalid action called on Pet instance:", action);
        }
    }
    return true; // Keep the message channel open for asynchronous response
});
// Using Alarms API for periodic actions
if (chrome.alarms) {
    chrome.alarms.create("savePetState", { periodInMinutes: 1 });
    chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
        if (alarm.name === "savePetState") {
            savePetState();
        }
    });
}
else {
    console.error("chrome.alarms is not available");
}
//# sourceMappingURL=background.js.map
```

The import statement here

```
import { Pet } from "./gameLogic/Pets";
```

Is missing the ".js" portion of the file's name, when adding it manually it works fine on chrome, I can load it and I can see all the logs and everything from the Pets class. Now the issue is, I have no clue on how to make the build process handle this automatically. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Errors you mentioned tells that there are some problems with **import** statements.

I tried your source code without this import statement:

```
import evolutionPaths, { EvolutionRequirement } from "./Evolutions";
```

As you didn't provide that file. Service worker registers and it works fine. Make sure you actually import everything, and you have **export** declarations in code you want to import.

Comment: I think you are right, but I'm not that good at configuring building process for vite (or for anything in all honesty) I'll edit the post to add the files missing, thank you so much for taking the time to look at this!!! You are awesome! :)